# My python discord bot which is supposed to automatically translate messages does not work

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to create a python discord translation bot which automatically detects non english languages using langdetect and translates them into english using deep-translator, but whenever I send a non english message, nothing happens and I get an error basically saying the language is not supported, even though it is, I am new to python so please dont judge if I am stupid. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Here is my code:

```
import os

import discord

from dotenv import load_dotenv

from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator

from langdetect import detect

load_dotenv()  

intents = discord.Intents.default()

intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event

async def on_ready():

    print(f'{client.user} is online')

@client.event

async def on_message(message):

    itself

    if message.author == client.user:

        return

    try:

        lang = detect(message.content)

    except:

        lang = 'unknown'

        

    if lang != 'en':

        

        translated_message = GoogleTranslator(source=lang, target='en').translate(message.content)

        response = f'{message.author.mention} said in {message.channel.name} ({lang}): {translated_message}'

       

        await message.channel.send(response)

TOKEN = os.environ.get("TOKEN")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

And here is the error I get:

> 2023-03-23 08:07:23 ERROR discord.client Ignoring exception in
> on_message Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/home/runner/Auto-translate/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py",
> line 441, in _run_event await coro(*args, **kwargs) File "main.py",
> line 33, in on_message translated_message =
> GoogleTranslator(source=lang, target='en').translate(message.content)
> File
> "/home/runner/Auto-translate/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deep_translator/google.py",
> line 39, in **init** super().**init**( File
> "/home/runner/Auto-translate/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deep_translator/base.py", line 44, in **init** self._source, self._target =
> self._map_language_to_code(source, target) File
> "/home/runner/Auto-translate/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deep_translator/base.py", line 84, in _map_language_to_code raise LanguageNotSupportedException(
> deep_translator.exceptions.LanguageNotSupportedException: unknown -->
> No support for the provided language. Please select on of the
> supported languages: {'afrikaans': 'af', 'albanian': 'sq', 'amharic':
> 'am', 'arabic': 'ar', 'armenian': 'hy', 'assamese': 'as', 'aymara':
> 'ay', 'azerbaijani': 'az', 'bambara': 'bm', 'basque': 'eu',
> 'belarusian': 'be', 'bengali': 'bn', 'bhojpuri': 'bho', 'bosnian':
> 'bs', 'bulgarian': 'bg', 'catalan': 'ca', 'cebuano': 'ceb',
> 'chichewa': 'ny', 'chinese (simplified)': 'zh-CN', 'chinese
> (traditional)': 'zh-TW', 'corsican': 'co', 'croatian': 'hr', 'czech':
> 'cs', 'danish': 'da', 'dhivehi': 'dv', 'dogri': 'doi', 'dutch': 'nl',
> 'english': 'en', 'esperanto': 'eo', 'estonian': 'et', 'ewe': 'ee',
> 'filipino': 'tl', 'finnish': 'fi', 'french': 'fr', 'frisian': 'fy',
> 'galician': 'gl', 'georgian': 'ka', 'german': 'de', 'greek': 'el',
> 'guarani': 'gn', 'gujarati': 'gu', 'haitian creole': 'ht', 'hausa':
> 'ha', 'hawaiian': 'haw', 'hebrew': 'iw', 'hindi': 'hi', 'hmong':
> 'hmn', 'hungarian': 'hu', 'icelandic': 'is', 'igbo': 'ig', 'ilocano':
> 'ilo', 'indonesian': 'id', 'irish': 'ga', 'italian': 'it', 'japanese':
> 'ja', 'javanese': 'jw', 'kannada': 'kn', 'kazakh': 'kk', 'khmer':
> 'km', 'kinyarwanda': 'rw', 'konkani': 'gom', 'korean': 'ko', 'krio':
> 'kri', 'kurdish (kurmanji)': 'ku', 'kurdish (sorani)': 'ckb',
> 'kyrgyz': 'ky', 'lao': 'lo', 'latin': 'la', 'latvian': 'lv',
> 'lingala': 'ln', 'lithuanian': 'lt', 'luganda': 'lg', 'luxembourgish':
> 'lb', 'macedonian': 'mk', 'maithili': 'mai', 'malagasy': 'mg',
> 'malay': 'ms', 'malayalam': 'ml', 'maltese': 'mt', 'maori': 'mi',
> 'marathi': 'mr', 'meiteilon (manipuri)': 'mni-Mtei', 'mizo': 'lus',
> 'mongolian': 'mn', 'myanmar': 'my', 'nepali': 'ne', 'norwegian': 'no',
> 'odia (oriya)': 'or', 'oromo': 'om', 'pashto': 'ps', 'persian': 'fa',
> 'polish': 'pl', 'portuguese': 'pt', 'punjabi': 'pa', 'quechua': 'qu',
> 'romanian': 'ro', 'russian': 'ru', 'samoan': 'sm', 'sanskrit': 'sa',
> 'scots gaelic': 'gd', 'sepedi': 'nso', 'serbian': 'sr', 'sesotho':
> 'st', 'shona': 'sn', 'sindhi': 'sd', 'sinhala': 'si', 'slovak': 'sk',
> 'slovenian': 'sl', 'somali': 'so', 'spanish': 'es', 'sundanese': 'su',
> 'swahili': 'sw', 'swedish': 'sv', 'tajik': 'tg', 'tamil': 'ta',
> 'tatar': 'tt', 'telugu': 'te', 'thai': 'th', 'tigrinya': 'ti',
> 'tsonga': 'ts', 'turkish': 'tr', 'turkmen': 'tk', 'twi': 'ak',
> 'ukrainian': 'uk', 'urdu': 'ur', 'uyghur': 'ug', 'uzbek': 'uz',
> 'vietnamese': 'vi', 'welsh': 'cy', 'xhosa': 'xh', 'yiddish': 'yi',
> 'yoruba': 'yo', 'zulu': 'zu'}

Comment: What is the value of `lang` when `GoogleTranslator(source=lang, target='en').translate(message.content)` is called? From the error code, it seems whatever the language that was returned by `detect` is not supported by `GoogleTranlator`.

Comment: @MarceloPaco I tried printing it in console and theres nothing, I guess the language is not even detected?

Comment: That could mean that `message.content` is empty. Have you checked it?

Comment: @MarceloPaco Oh yeah youre right, I printed it in the console and its always empty, so do you know why this is happening?

Comment: I don't know why its happening. I'm just going on intuition and debugging principles. Can you test/verify that you are receiving messages. There's probably a bug somewhere in your code that's making `message.content` empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `lang = 'unknown'` to `lang = 'en'` or `return`. Google doesn't have  a "unknown" language, and so you either have to have a base case (english) or not do anything (by `return`ing).

Comment: Oh I already tried that it does not do anything